# Can I avoid this syntax highlighting confusion?

Tags: django, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

I have the following in my Django view:

```
<a title="{{ photo.time_taken|date:"N jS, 'y" }}" href='...' > {# ' #}
  ...
</a>
```

The problem is with wanting to format my date with the year as `'13`. The quotes get all confused, so I've had to put a django comment on the end to 'close' the quote, otherwise all following code is mis-highlighted. Is there a better way around this?

I'm using Sublime Text 2, with [Djaneiro](https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro).

Comment: why is your href inside your filtered value? `<a title="{{ photo.time_taken|date:'N jS, \'y'}}" href='...' >` this feels better or am i missing out something?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo Agh, the broken highlighting confused me. Should be correct now.

Comment: Find a better highlighting description file. *shrug*